# How to encrypt files other than .txt usin AES in java?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am developing a java application which allows the user to encrypt multiple files. I am using AES with 128 bit key. I have the following issues in this work:-

1. The implemented AES algorithm works fine for only .txt files but it doesn't work on any other file type such as Office document, images etc. My question is that **does AES works for all types of data or only text files?** I have searched alot but all examples I found use .txt files.
2. Currently I read the contents of the file into a string then encrypt it then write the encrypted string back to the file. My question is that **is there a way to encrypt files without reading the contents of the file?**
3. **Is there a way to decrypt directory(folders) and all its contents using AES?** By "decrypting directory" I mean that it can't be opened and it show some error message when it is tried to be opened.
4. Also the encrypted files can be edited,deleted,moved, copied and renamed. I want that nobody could perform these actions on files that my application have encrypted. **How to do this?**

Following is the code I am using but only works for .txt files not for others. Don't know what is the problem:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class JavaCrypt
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           File f=new File("D:/a.txt");
           int ch;

               StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
               FileInputStream fin = null;
               try {
               fin = new FileInputStream(f);
               while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1)
                   strContent.append((char) ch);
                   fin.close();
                   } 
               catch (Exception e) {
                   System.out.println(e);
                   }

               System.out.println("Original string: " +strContent.toString()+"\n");
               // Get the KeyGenerator

           KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
           kgen.init(128); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available


           // Generate the secret key specs.
           SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
           byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();

           SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");


           // Instantiate the cipher

           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

           byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(strContent.toString().getBytes());

           System.out.println("encrypted string: " + encrypted.toString());

           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
           byte[] original =cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

           String originalString = new String(original);
           System.out.println("Original string: " +originalString);
         }
}
```

Comment: Point 1 is simply not true. AES works on binary data, no matter the kind. If it doesn't work for you, it's your implementations fault, and you need to post your code. Likely it's a encoding and not encryption related issue.

Comment: Point 2 Why strings? Just work on binary data. And you obviously need to read a file to encrypt it. How else should it work? Magic?

Comment: @CodeInChaos point 2 is related to point 4. I mean that can point 4 be achieved without reading the contents of the file?

Comment: Point 3 and 4 are outside the scope of encryption. Unless you want to create a full blown virtual file system. And of course in that case, it's still possible to delete the whole container at once.

Comment: @CodeInChaos It means that there is no solution or way to solve to these problems???

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, AES works for all data.
2. No.
3. Yes.
4. Zip the directory and contents, then encrypt the Zip file.  Use an HMAC to ensure that nobody messes with the encrypted file.

You say, " Kindly reply ASAP as I have to submit this project in a couple of days and I am stucked very hard in these problems."  As you have now learned, leaving things to the last minute is not a good way to get good results: Proper Planning Prevents Poor Performance.

If you had looked at things earlier, then you would not have too little time left to solve your problems.